# Add a fa-icon in JHipster

Tags: jhipster

**My goal:** use a fa-icon which as not been imported yet by JHipster

**My try:** add the fa-icon GrinHearts manually in the app.vendor.ts file using the following code and then run yarn run webpack:build command

```
/* after changing this file run 'yarn run webpack:build' */
/* tslint:disable */
import '../content/css/vendor.css';

// Imports all fontawesome core and solid icons

import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core';
import {
    faUser,
    faSort,
    faSync,
    faEye,
    faBan,
    faTimes,
    faArrowLeft,
    faSave,
    faPlus,
    faPencilAlt,
    faBars,
    faThList,
    faUserPlus,
    faRoad,
    faTachometerAlt,
    faHeart,
    faList,
    faBell,
    faBook,
    faHdd,
    faFlag,
    faWrench,
    faClock,
    faCloud,
    faSignOutAlt,
    faSignInAlt,
    faCalendarAlt,
    faSearch,
    faTrashAlt,
    faAsterisk,
    faTasks,
    faHome,
    faGrinHearts
} from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';

// Adds the SVG icon to the library so you can use it in your page
library.add(faUser);
library.add(faSort);
library.add(faSync);
library.add(faEye);
library.add(faBan);
library.add(faTimes);
library.add(faArrowLeft);
library.add(faSave);
library.add(faPlus);
library.add(faPencilAlt);
library.add(faBars);
library.add(faHome);
library.add(faThList);
library.add(faUserPlus);
library.add(faRoad);
library.add(faTachometerAlt);
library.add(faHeart);
library.add(faList);
library.add(faBell);
library.add(faTasks);
library.add(faBook);
library.add(faHdd);
library.add(faFlag);
library.add(faWrench);
library.add(faClock);
library.add(faCloud);
library.add(faSignOutAlt);
library.add(faSignInAlt);
library.add(faCalendarAlt);
library.add(faSearch);
library.add(faTrashAlt);
library.add(faAsterisk);
library.add(faGrinHearts);

// jhipster-needle-add-element-to-vendor - JHipster will add new menu items here
```

**My issue:** I get this error

ERROR in */src/main/webapp/app/vendor.ts
(41,5): Module '"*/node_modules/@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons/index"' has no exported member 'faGrinHearts'.

Could somebody help me please?

Thanks!

Comment: Which version of `@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons` is configured in your package.json? Your icon has been added in 5.1.0

Comment: "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "1.2.0-11",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "5.1.0-8", The version should be ok.

Comment: Using "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "1.2.2" and 
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "5.2.0" and I can see node_modules/@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icon/faGrinHearts.d.ts  in my project. Can you see it also?

Comment: No I don't have it. My version is too old then. Thanks. At least I know where to find them now. I just generated the project with JHipster. My guess was that this kind of library was on date without the need of checking for last version. I will check how to update some of them in JHipster. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to update your `@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons` package, the `FaGrinHearts` icon is not included in `v5.1.0-8`, only in `v5.1.0+`.  I'd recommend using the latest version, which is `v5.2.0`.  You can see the versions and the order they were released on [npmjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons?activeTab=versions)